# Most frequent combination of words/characters SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am analysing data in a 'RawDataDescriptions' table with a 'description' field that was open end for users to input.

I'm looking for ways to broadly categorise the descriptions by phrases or a string of characters that frequently show up (including a count of how many times they occur).

I have no specific words or phrases to look for necessarily where i can use a 'like' statement, instead i'm looking for commonalities between the fields.

Whilst looking for this through other questions, i managed to find a query which i adjusted for my own table that gets out the most common word (Pasted below), but of course one word alone provides little -if any -insight into the descriptions.

Is it possible to make a query that would provide a count of phrases and not just single words? if so, what would the main components of it be?

```
WITH E1(N) AS 
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM (VALUES
        (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
    ) t(N)
),
E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b),
E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b)
SELECT
    x.Item,
    COUNT(*)
FROM RawDataDescriptions p
CROSS APPLY (
SELECT 
        ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(p.[Description], l.N1, l.L1)))
        FROM (
            SELECT s.N1,
                L1 = ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ',p.[Description],s.N1),0)-
s.N1,4000)
            FROM(
                SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                SELECT t.N+1 
                FROM(
                    SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(p.[Description])/2,0))
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
                    FROM E4
                ) t(N)
                WHERE SUBSTRING(p.[Description] ,t.N,1) = ' '
            ) s(N1)
        ) l(N1, L1)
) x
WHERE x.item <> ''
GROUP BY x.Item
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

*Edit - not doable. Alternative desired outcome:

Sample table

```
Id | Description  
---+--------------------------
01 | Customer didn't like it  
02 | Person liked it  
03 | Person didn't like it  
04 | Client didn't like it  
05 | person liked it
```

@Parameter = 3

Desired result  :

```
string           | count  
-----------------+-------
didn't like it   | 3  
Person liked it  | 2
```

edit 2** the original question was doable - see answer

Comment: I don't think you can do this. It is possible to do it for a single word like because it is clear what a word is. But define a phrase....it could be two words, three or ten. You would have to literally parse every possible combination of multiple words for each row. That could be literally thousands of possibilities for entries with just a few words in them.

Comment: What if alternatively i did something similar to the query in the OP but for 3 words instead of just the one?

Comment: You could do that. You will have NumberOfWords - 2 as the number of possible phrases for every row.

Comment: How would I code to adjust the number of words?

Comment: You can't really just modify this to do that. The code you posted is parsing your strings into rows using the space as a delimiter. You would have to start all over to get your values into three word phrases. You also need to decide what you do with phrases that only have one or two words. What do you do with those?

Comment: I suppose I would want the query to say something like group any substring containing @int words within each record that have a count of >1

Comment: So only those that have more than 1 word got it. What about rows with 2 words? Can't put that as a phrase of three words. I think you need to provide a table, some sample data and desired output. This is just way too vague at this point to even think about putting together any code.

Comment: no as in the @int parameter would be the number of words and the 'count >1' would be if those 3 words occur in 2 or more records

Comment: What three words? You have something in mind here but I don't get what you are trying to do. Provide some details.

Comment: so my column is [description] (varchar). The Table is RawDataDescription. [Description] is full of text that users input. I want to see how frequent any sequence of x number of words within each row are with x being a parameter i pass (this way i can make it 3, 4 or 5 words etc). If they only show up the once ( which many will) I don't need them to be selected hence the idea of  having the count >1

Comment: OK I will try one last time. Can you please post some sample data (just a few rows) and the desired output with a given set of parameters?

Comment: edited in the OP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one option.  I have several concerns, like punctuation, control characters, and especially performance on large tables

**Example**

```
Declare @RawDataDescriptions Table ([Id] varchar(50),[Description] varchar(50))
Insert Into @RawDataDescriptions Values 
 ('01','Customer didn''t like it')
,('02','Person liked it')
,('03','Person didn''t like it')
,('04','Client didn''t like it')
,('05','person liked it')

;with cte as (
    Select Id
          ,B.* 
      From  @RawDataDescriptions A
      Cross Apply (
                    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.[Description],' ','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                  ) B 
)
Select Phrase
      ,Cnt  = count(*)
 From  cte A
 Cross Apply (
     Select Phrase = stuff((Select ' '+RetVal
                            From  cte 
                            Where ID = A.ID
                              and RetSeq between A.RetSeq and A.RetSeq+2
                            Order By RetSeq
                            For XML Path('')),1,1,'')

             ) B
  Where Phrase like '% % %'
  Group By Phrase
  Having count(*)>1
  Order By 2 Desc
```

**Returns**

```
Phrase           Cnt
didn't like it   3
Person liked it  2
```

---

> **UPDATE - TVF - Better Performance**

I decided that I may want to turn this into a a Table-Valued Function, and was shocked by the performance gains.  For example, I have 130,000 descriptions from FRED (Federal Reserve Economic Data), and I was able to generate a list of common phrases (n words) in 9 seconds.

**Usage**

```
Select Phrase = B.RetVal
      ,Cnt    = count(*)
 From YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse-Phrase](A.YourColumn,' ',4) B
 Group By B.RetVal
 Having count(*)>1
 Order By 2 Desc
```

**The TVF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse-Phrase] (@String varchar(max),@Delimeter varchar(25),@WordCnt int)
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
 with cte as (
      Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
            ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
      From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimeter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
      Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
)
Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select Null))
      ,B.RetVal
 From  cte A
 Cross Apply (Select RetVal = stuff((Select ' '+RetVal From cte Where RetSeq between A.RetSeq and A.RetSeq+@WordCnt-1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') ) B
 Where B.RetVal like Replicate('% ',@WordCnt-1)+'%'
);
--Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse-Phrase]('This is some text that I want parsed',' ',4)
```

Comment: This is pretty slick John. I struggled with it for a little bit (stupid case sensitive collation). But it works great. I even tweaked it slightly to receive a length parameter and it works well. I just tweaked the Where clause to use replicate.

Comment: @SeanLange If interested, I converted this into a TVF.  The performance gains were shocking.   See EDIT/Update

Comment: @SaleemKhan Happy it helped

Answer (score 0):

You can enable `Microsoft Full Text Index` on the table & perform these kind of finding frequent words and characters analysis on the table.

- [sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-fts-index-keywords-by-document-transact-sql)
- [sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-fts-index-keywords-by-property-transact-sql)
- [sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-fts-index-keywords-by-document-transact-sql)